# rotational cryptanalysis on modulo multiplication?

Tags: cryptanalysis, arx

I saw the paper 'Rotational Cryptanalysis of ARX', it is effective against design primitives using XOR, addition, and rotation.

http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2010/61470339/61470339.pdf

However about those that use modulo multiplication (e.g. Multiplication modulo $2^{16}+1$, where the all-zero word (0x0000) is
interpreted as $2^{16}$ (denoted by a circled dot ⊙))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rotational cryptanalysis considers applying the transformation $E$ to both $X$ and $\overrightarrow{X}$, where
$$
\overrightarrow{(x_1, x_2,x_3,\ldots, x_n)} = (x_{r+1},x_{r+2},\ldots, x_n, x_1,\ldots, x_r)
$$
for some integer $r$. You know that $\overrightarrow{X} \oplus \overrightarrow{Y} = \overrightarrow{X\oplus Y}$ always, and
$$
\overrightarrow{X} \boxplus\overrightarrow{Y} = \overrightarrow{(X\boxplus Y)}
$$
with quite high probability.

For the modulo multiplication the property does not seem to hold.  I guess you were thinking of applying it to the [IDEA block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm). However, in some situations a modified property holds. For instance, if $X = q2^l$  and $Y = p2^t$ for some small $q,l,t,p$, then
$$
\overrightarrow{X} \odot \overrightarrow{Y} = (q2^{l+r}) (p2^{t+r}) = (pq)2^{t+l+2r} = 
\overrightarrow{\overrightarrow{(X\odot Y)}},
$$
i.e. you have double rotation (again with some probability). I wonder if you could exploit in the attacks, because generally we want the same rotation distance $r$ in all internal variables.

To summarize, no one has yet applied rotational cryptanalysis to the multiplication, though there are hopes.

Comment: Yeah you are right!. Since the input $X$ is split to 2 parts: $(x_1,x_2)$ for the MA structure, should we consider rotational cryptanalysis for each $x_i$?

Comment: I never tried a rotational attack with distinct rotation distances, so I do not know how it could work..

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as valid if you consider it so.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, just curious. Can we apply rotational cryptanalysis for bitwise permutation operations in ciphers?

Comment: Bitwise permutations usually do not preserve the rotation distance.