# What is the probability equation of rotational cryptanalysis on modulo multiplication?

Tags: cryptanalysis, arx, probability

The answer in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20764/rotational-cryptanalysis-on-modulo-multiplication) defined how to calculate the probability of rotational cryptanalysis on modulo multiplication $\odot$. This [paper](https://cryptolux.org/images/5/5b/Rotational_Cryptanalysis_of_Skein.pdf) defined an algebraic equation of how to calculate the rotational probability of modular addition $\boxplus$ which is

$$
\textbf{P}(\overrightarrow{X\boxplus Y} = \overrightarrow{X}\boxplus\overrightarrow{Y}) = \frac{1}{4}(1+2^{-r} + 2^{r-n}+ 2^{-n}) 
$$
where $r$ is rotational value and smaller than modular value $n$

and experimental results of 8-bit ($n$) addition shows similar values of

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
r & f \\
\hline
0 & 65536 \\
1 & 24768 \\
2 & 20800 \\
3 & 19008 \\
4 & 18496 \\
5 & 19008 \\
6 & 20800 \\
7 & 24768 \\
\end{array}
$$

where f is the frequency of 
$
\overrightarrow{X\boxplus Y} = \overrightarrow{X}\boxplus\overrightarrow{Y}
$
for each $r$ . the probability of 1 bit rotation is $\frac{24768}{65536}$ is around $.378$ (nearly same as in the table in ). the other thing is you find reflection of frequency values , 1 bit rotation is equal to 7 bit rotation (2 and 6 so on). The following figure shows a flipped bell distribution of rotational modulo addition.

[image]

**The next step**

I conducted the same experiment (8 bit size) but with the following equation (double rotation).

$$
\overrightarrow{X} \odot \overrightarrow{Y} =
\overrightarrow{\overrightarrow{(X\odot Y)}}
$$
the following table shows the frequency:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
r & f \\
\hline
0 & 65536 \\
1 & 4730 \\
2 & 1082 \\
3 & 904 \\
4 & 1664 \\
5 & 904 \\
6 & 1082 \\
7 & 4730 \\
\end{array}
$$

[image]
from the table and figure, i see there is a reflection of frequency values (suggesting a similar equation of rotational cryptanalysis probability is applied as following:

$$
\textbf{P}(\overrightarrow{X} \odot \overrightarrow{Y} =
\overrightarrow{\overrightarrow{(X\odot Y)}}) = \frac{1}{t}(1+2^{-e_0} + 2^{e_0-e_1}+ 2^{-e_1}) 
$$

**Question**

if my guess is right , how to calculate the  $t , e_0 , e_1$ values?

**NOTE** 
Iam happy to share the source code in the question.

Comment: Ask a clear question up-front.  What does "guess" refer to?  How in the world does your "guess" change the fact of how the t,e0,e1 values will be calculated?  Which experiment are you referring to?

Comment: if i understand your comment right , I mapped the equation used in addition expression to multiplication. my guess was t, eo, e1 are only function of rotation constant (r) and size (n) , however , after ploting the tables  of rotational addition and multiplication , I found the two plots are different , the addition plot is smooth fliped bell distribution , the multiplication is not (there is a bumb when r =4 f=1644) , I guess the proposed equation is not correct